# Getting sequential photos using get request with React and axios

Tags: reactjs, image, axios, get

There is a data like the following coming from an endpoint. I show each element (bpr, bpr v0.0.7) and its content in this data in a table. I need to show the image in the data that comes with the name modelIconLocation by making a get request in an img component. How can I do this using axios in a react project?

````
{
    "apiKeys": [
        {
            "featureSet": {
                "face": {
                    "bpr": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "bpr_v0.0.7": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                        }
                    ],
                    "bpr_v0.1.5": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                        }
                    ],
                    "bpr_v0.1.6": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                        }
                    ],
                    "bpr_v0.1.8": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                        }
                    ],
                    "hr": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                        }
                    ],
                    "hrv": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                        }
                    ],
                    "rr": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "fingertip": {
                    "bpr": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                        }
                    ],
                    "hr": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                        }
                    ],
                    "hrv": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                        }
                    ],
                    "rr": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                        }
                    ],
                    "spo2": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "featureSet": {
                "face": {
                    "bpr": [
                        {
                            "modelIconLocation": "someurl.png",
                            }
                        }
                    ],
...
```
````